# How to split elements of list with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Given this list:

```
['MIA', 'BOS', '08:17 AM', '-107', '-103', '08:17 AM', '+1 -111', '-1 +103', u'91', u'93']
```

I want to split `+1 -111`, `-1 +103` on the space for the result of:

```
['MIA', 'BOS', '08:17 AM', '-107', '-103', '08:17 AM', '+1', '-111', '-1', '+103', u'91', u'93']
```

This is the regex I will need:

```
(?<=\d)\s(?=[-+]\d\d\d)
```

but apparently I don't know how to apply it to  a list. Obviously a solution with slicing, like split always the `nth` element of the list is not welcomed option. I prefer this to be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your existing `re` you can use the following which flattens out the single element splits:

```
import re
from itertools import chain

some_list = ['MIA', 'BOS', '08:17 AM', '-107', '-103', '08:17 AM', '+1 -111', '-1 +103', u'91', u'93']
print list(chain.from_iterable(re.split('(?<=\d)\s(?=[-+]\d\d\d)', s) for s in some_list))
# ['MIA', 'BOS', '08:17 AM', '-107', '-103', '08:17 AM', '+1', '-111', '-1', '+103', u'91', u'93']
```

Comment: `..from_iterable(imap(re.compile(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=[-+]\d\d\d)').split, some_list)))`

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is the most efficient way, but:

```
output = []
for x in input:
    if re.search('(?<=\d)\s(?=[-+]\d\d\d)', x):
        output += x.split(" ")
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using a list comprehension:

```
import re

lst = ['MIA', 'BOS', '08:17 AM', '-107', '-103', '08:17 AM', '+1 -111', '-1 +103', u'91', u'93']
result = [s for x in lst for s in re.split(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=[-+]\d\d\d)', x)]
```

Result:

```
>>> result
['MIA', 'BOS', '08:17 AM', '-107', '-103', '08:17 AM', '+1', '-111', '-1', '+103', u'91', u'93']
```

Or to modify the list in place:

```
for i in range(len(lst)-1, -1, -1):
    lst[i:i+1] = re.split(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=[-+]\d\d\d)', lst[i])
```

Note that looping from the end of the list to the front is important here.

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator can be very efficient, specially for huge inputs and if you intend discard the result after iterating over it (and is more elegant than using an intermediate list):

```
def split_elements(list_, regex):
    for element in list_:
        for sub_element in re.split(regex, element):
            yield sub_element

output = [x for x in split_elements(input, regex)]
```

For the sample input:

```
>>> l = ['MIA', 'BOS', '08:17 AM', '-107', '-103', '08:17 AM', 
         '+1 -111', '-1 +103', u'91', u'93']

>>> list(split_elements(l, r'(?<=\d)\s(?=[-+]\d\d\d)'))
['MIA', 'BOS', '08:17 AM', '-107', '-103', '08:17 AM', '+1', '-111', '-1',
 '+103', u'91', u'93']
```

It is almost the same technique used in Jon Clements' answer, without itertools (one-liners may get hard to read after a few weeks).